# Como fazer uma consulta em um intervalo de data no mysql?

Tags: mysql

Quero fazer uma comparação se a data esta dentro de 30 dias.

Por exemplo, tenho a data 10/01/2016 e quero que me retorne todos os resultados com datas 30 dias próximos a essa por exemplo, 09/02/2016.

Comment: Qual tipo de data você está usando?! Date, DateTime, Timestamp?! Tem que citar senão fica difícil.

Comment: esta com varchar mas da pra converter para date e so utilizar STR_TO_DATE(data, "%d/%m/%Y")

Comment: 30 dias próximos em que sentido? +30, -30, +15 e -15, +30 e -30? qual deles?

Comment: Guilherme, conseguiu resolver seu problema com a resposta? Ou precisa de mais alguma informação?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Eu costumo fazer desta forma abaixo. Uso `NOW()` para pegar a data atual e faço uma subtração no intervalo de 30 dias usando `INTERVAL 30 DAY`. Na *query* eu faço a comparação se a data de criação (`created_at` do tipo `timestamp`) é maior, então me retorne todos os dados:

```
SELECT * FROM `task` WHERE created_at > (NOW() - INTERVAL 30 DAY)
```

Assim todos os resultados estarão dentre os 30 dias.

Comment: isso conta também no mês de 28, 29 dias ?

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 A pergunta cita uma comparação de um intervalo de 30 dias, independente de qual mês. Desta forma eu consigo obter um resultado condizente com a pergunta, baseado nos meus testes e considerando `timestamp`.

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 engraçado que as questões mais importantes da pergunta as pessoas só colocam nos comentários. Aí a gente tem que deduzir o que a pessoa quer dizer. Aposto que você passou muito por isso. Abraços

Comment: Sim eu sei da pergunta, mas gostaria de sabe se no mês de fevereiro isso funciona também dessa forma.

Comment: @GOKUSSJ4 30 dias é 30 dias amigão. Se a gente tiver em 1 de março, contando 30 dias para trás, dependendo do ano claro, vai ultrapassar e cair no mês de Janeiro! Abs.

Comment: Legal, não sabia dessa forma no mysql. +1. mas eu acho que é 30 dias pra frente.

Comment: A dica do seamusd parece viavel, mas se o cliente editar a data no computador dele, isso não afeta os resultados ? ou o php vai pegar a data atual de algum servidor ?

Comment: @OtavioFagundes data atual do servidor. Abraços

Comment: @OtavioFagundes a a função NOW é independente do PHP. Isso é direto na query. Abraços

Comment: obrigado por me tirar essa duvida, eu também estava precisando disso

Comment: @OtavioFagundes só deixar o +1 e tá tudo certo. Kkkkkkk briks. Precisando só dá um grito aqui. Abraços

Answer (score 2):

Você pode usar a expressão;

```
SELECT * FROM `table` 
where STR_TO_DATE(data, "%d/%m/%Y") >= STR_TO_DATE('10/01/2016', "%d/%m/%Y")
and STR_TO_DATE(data, "%d/%m/%Y") <= STR_TO_DATE(09/02/2016', "%d/%m/%Y");
```

Ou ainda usar o `between`:

```
   SELECT * FROM `table` 
    where STR_TO_DATE(data, "%d/%m/%Y") between STR_TO_DATE('10/01/2016', "%d/%m/%Y")
  and STR_TO_DATE(09/02/2016', "%d/%m/%Y");
```

Comment: isso nao funciona pq preciso de todos os resultados 30 dias entre a dataparametro2

Comment: Funciona, só depende o que você passar nos parâmetros.

Answer (score 1):

Consegui resolver assim

```
SELECT * FROM PESSOAS WHERE DATEDIFF(STR_TO_DATE(ANIVERSARIO, "%d/%m/%Y"),STR_TO_DATE('10/01/2013', "%d/%m/%Y")) BETWEEN -30 and 30
```

Comment: Assim, você só retorna 10 dias...

Comment: editei, mas a sua dica me ajudou demais, muito obrigado